# Best Platform For Facebook Game

Tags: silverlight, facebook

I realize the question seems very broad and subjective, but I'm mostly looking for suggestions on a platform choice so that I don't paint myself into a corner later on (I'm more familiar with client-side programming, so excuse the lack of proper server jargon).

First: I am building a game. It will be multiplayer, with some real time interaction between players. Obviously, I'm not talking FPS, or even at the scale of a RTS, but something similar to what the Google Channel API does in terms of messaging.

**I'm looking for the best Server/Client pairing.**

Now, I've come to the realization as a result of my day job, that C# has become by far my best language. I'm also getting very familiar with WPF, so Silverlight seems like a natural extension of that understanding.

From what I can find search-wise, Silverlight is not a popular Facebook app platform. Is there a reason for this?

**What's the "standard" client-server pairing?** Is it Flash for the front end, what's the back end?

Does anyone have a favorite pairing? Easy to prototype/dev test?

**Is there a good clientside platform choice that has an open source game engine, and can also reach a majority of browsers (i.e. the iPad as well as desktops)?**

Edit: I have also stumbled upon the Windows Azure Social Toolkit. Anybody have an opinion on using that as a starting place?
http://watgames.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most social games use Flash for the front end because of its market saturation, roughly 98% right now. If you use anything else, you will lose potential users for two reasons: 1) some users cannot install the platform you want to use (e.g. a work computer with no administrator access) and 2) some users can, but they don't want to install the platform you want to use.

As for the back-end, there is no "standard" and is more a matter of taste and preference. Use what you're most comfortable with and prefer to code in.

Just make sure whatever back-end architecture you choose allows you to add more application servers  and database servers without having to bring the game down. The easiest solution is probably distributed key-value databases (e.g. Cassandra) for this.

Comment: I had figured the flash aspect had something to do with market saturation, and I had thought about the issue of not being able to install Silverlight in a work environment. I looked at the HTML5 offerings, and for games, it seems to be less developed than other platforms. Is Flash really the best option?

Comment: At the moment, Flash is definitely the "best" option, and with Flash 11 and 3d support, it's going to become even more popular for web games.